# Finding the pixel that minimizes the distance between two sets

Tags: matlab, pixel, distance, minimize

I have a statement trying to implement but confused on how to do so. This is my issue:

- I have an image where I have set some pixels of interest (region of interest) to the value `1`. So, we can say that we now have a set with the following values `1s` where each `1` here represents a particular location in the image.

> C = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];

For example, say `img` for simplicity here is the matrix `x` as follows:

```
x = [2 3 5; 5 4 5; 6 4 3; 6 5 4; 6 54 3; 6 5 3];
```

`x` will have a degree of membership `y` based on which we set some values to `1`. To clarify, for each pixel for which `y` = `1` we set that pixel to `1`. So, let's say `y` is:

```
y = [0 1 0; 0 1 1; 1 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 1; 1 1 1];
```

So, `C` contains 10 `1s`. For instance the first `1` represents the location `x(1,2)` and so forth...

- Now, I want to check the `4-neighbourhoods` of the pixels in `C` but that at the same time not in `C`. That is, on the surroundings.
- Now, for those pixels that belong to the surroundings and are four neighbors of `C` I want to select that pixel `p` that **minimizes the distance** between `x` and `C`.

Is it clear now? Do you know how I can go around it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here.  However, you say you are confused by the phrase "minimise the distance"; if it helps, that *might* mean the distance between the pixel values, i.e. how different the image looks.  Perhaps you could give more information and say whether you think my guess would make sense for your problem.

Comment: What is the `size` of `img` and `p`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will add more information to my question

Comment: Maybe you can solve this problem manually for a small matrix... this will help us to write a generalized psuedo code

Comment: What would be the criterion according to which a distance would be minimal?

Comment: @Jonas. This will depend I think on the distance function and comparing the results of those distance functions

Comment: @prog: So... what is the question then? Given `y`, how do you find all the candidate pixels?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the pixels that are 4-neighbors of the pixels in `y`, but not `y` themselves, you can use `imdilate` like this:

```
msk = zeros(3);
msk(2,:) = 1;
msk(:,2) = 1;

tmp = imdilate(y,msk);

result = tmp & ~y;
```

Now you can get the pixel values as `C(result)`, and apply your distance function.